# Tomcat as Proxy Server

Tags: java, node.js, tomcat, spring-boot

We have made a Spring boot based Web Application. Which has only static resources all html pages as angular 2 application under it.

The angular 2 application makes REST API calls which are served from different server.

I want to configure tomcat in such a way that all calls starting with /backend should be forwarded to different server and rest all request should be served from same server.

It should act like node server where we provide a proxy-config.json.

Can you suggest any implementation?

Comment: Will the client (browser?) be making the calls to `/backend` or will the server-side REST API itself be making those calls?

Comment: No the client side will interact with backend server. If the api calls starts with /backend the tomcat server should forward it to other server and if it does not it should serve it from its static folder only.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat does not come bundled with anything that would be considered a proxy server. If you want to proxy requests through Tomcat, you'll have to use a 3rd-party solution. Suggestions for 3rd-party solutions are out of scope for Stack Overflow.